# Bounded Holomorphic function on Right half plane.

Tags: complex-analysis

Does there exist a Bounded Holomorphic function defined on Right half plane which have all $\sqrt{n}$ as root for all natural number $n$?

I guess It is a just $0$ function.

But How Could I approach this one?

(I've been trying to use Blascke product.)

Thanks!

Comment: What is the "right upper half plane"?

Comment: probably $x>0, y>0$.

Comment: Yes, pGroups got a point. Thanks.

Comment: $\sqrt{n}$ is not in there?

Comment: OMG, I lose my mind, I fixed this, Right upper half -> Right half. Sorry confusing you.

Answer (score 2):

If $f$ is a bounded non-constant holomorphic function on the disc then $\{1-|z| \mid f(z)=0\}$ is summable (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/560784/holomorphic-function-having-finitely-many-zeros-in-the-open-unit-disc/560947?s=2|0.0710#560947)). The function $$z\mapsto\frac{1+z}{1-z}$$ maps the unit disc onto the right half plane. The pre-image of $\sqrt{n}$ is $$\frac{\sqrt{n}-1}{\sqrt{n}+1} = 1 -\frac2{\sqrt{n}+1}$$
so a bounded function on the unit disc with those roots must be identically zero.  Therefore also a bounded function on the right half plane with roots $\sqrt{n}$ must be identically zero.

Comment: I edited my deleted answer, but now I see that it matches your answer. (+1)

Comment: Thanks! But Why "a bounded function on the unit disc with those roots must be identically zero."? I know preimage of $\sqrt{n}$ goes to $1$. So....?

Comment: @nicksohn: I undeleted my answer. Look at the Szegö Theorem.

Comment: Ah, Uniqueness Theorem, Right?

Comment: @nicksohn The numbers $(\sqrt{n}-1)/(\sqrt{n}+1)$ converge too slowly to $1$ to be the roots of a bounded non-zero function on the disc ($2/(\sqrt{n}+1)$ is not summable).

Answer (score 1):

The function
$$
z\mapsto\frac{z-1}{z+1}
$$
maps the right half plane to the unit circle. The points $\sqrt{n}$ get mapped to
$$
\frac{\sqrt{n}-1}{\sqrt{n}+1}
$$
Since
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(1-\left|\frac{\sqrt{n}-1}{\sqrt{n}+1}\right|\right)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac2{\sqrt{n}+1}=\infty
$$
the [Szegö Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blaschke_product#Szeg.C5.91_theorem) says that the only bounded function on the unit disk with those roots vanishes identically.

Comment: Right upper half -> Right half. Sorry confusing you.

Comment: Thanks!  Szegö Theorem look fine, But Somewhat.. Too difficult to me for now. I'll check it very soon.

Comment: @nicksohn : Are you sure you didn't learn about the condition when studying Blaschke products?